# What is the plural form of 'Achilles' when referring to the Achilles tendon?

Tags: grammatical-number, proper-nouns, irregular-plurals

In Oxford Learner's Dictionary, under *Achilles tendon*, it says that

> Achilles tendon = Achilles

Then the plural of 'Achilles tendon' is 'Achilles tendons'.

But, what is the plural form of "Achilles"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why should you want "the plural of Achilles"? Nouns (common or proper) used as the non-final element of compounds don't usually take a plural ending; and if they do, they always take it. They don't change when the whole phrase is plural:

> kitchen unit -> kitchen units.
>
> cable provider -> cable providers.

and

> glasses case -> glasses cases.

If you really want to talk about more than one Achilles, then most people would say "Achilleses", but people often aren't sure how to write it. I suspect some people would say "two Achilles" (like "two series").

Answer (score 1):

Google finds around a dozen hits for *"two achilles are"*, and only one for *"two achilleses are"*. So I would say the consensus is that the plural of *Achilles* is *Achilles*.

However pluralizing *achilles* is so rare that I assume most people who do it aren't copying the plural form from things they've heard, but coming up with it *de novo*. So I would be very heistant to call *achilleses* wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it's because words ending in unstressed /iz/ already "sound" plural: *fillies, axis>axes, basis>bases, crisis>crises, Kingdom of the Two Sicilies, gives me the willies*.

Comment: @tchrist: that's probably why. And two additional words: *species>species* and *series>series.*

Comment: Be­sides those two you note from Latin’s 5ᵗʰ-de­clen­sion, other ex­am­ples in­vari­ant in the plu­ral be­cause of al­ready end­ing in un­stressed /iːz/ (UK) or /iz/ (US) are *Pekinese* for the dog and *Si­amese* for the cat. As far as I can dis­cern, **ᴀʟʟ *-ese* de­monyms and lo­gonyms** end­ing in un­stressed /iz/ strongly re­sist (block?) fur­ther /ǝz/ in­flec­tions, whether to make them plu­ral or to make them pos­ses­sive. Same with *Mercedes* be­ing in­vari­ant, be it car make or wom­an’s name. That’s why I be­lieve these all op­er­ate un­der some kind of un­taught sound law.